# Saving an image in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I want to save modified(masked) image I used imsave and imwrite functions but it didnt work.

```
%Original
I=imread('sample_gray_256.tif');
%Mask
M=imread('Mask.tif');
M1=im2bw(M,0.5);
%Masked Sample
MS=I;
MS(M1==0)= 0;
```

I masked the image but I want to save it current folder. 
Which format should I save? Which one is the most qualified?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please refer the function to write the image [file](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imwrite.html). Basic usage:

```
imwrite(MS,'maskedImg.png')
```

Now to answer the question which one is qualified depends on the usage. I would just save it back to tif if you are using all the images in same format. There are a bunch of posts comparing different formats, some of them are:

http://imagej.net/Principles

http://1stwebdesigner.com/image-file-types/